# python csv two columns with same name

Tags: python, csv

Is there a way to use the python csv module to save a csv which has two columns of the same name?

This is my function

```
def DictListToCsv(Data, FileName, FieldNames):
    with open(FileName, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = FieldNames, dialect = 'excel', delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(Data)
```

Every approach i try would involve at some point having a dictionary with two headers named the same, which is of course not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using pandas module ? 
Convert your data into pandas dataframe ("df") and then use :

```
df.columns=['x','x']
```

and finally, save it to a csv file :

```
 df.to_csv(r'/home/ishan/Desktop/a.csv',header=True, index=False)
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? 
[update] setting now the delimiter and line terminator

```
def DictListToCsv(Data, FileName, FieldNames):
    with open(FileName, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel', delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(FieldNames)
        writer.writerows(Data)

FieldNames = ['Spam','Spam','Spam','Spam','more Spam']
Data = [[11,12,13,14,15],[21,22,23,24,25]]

DictListToCsv(Data, 'eggs.csv', FieldNames)
```

Comment: This gives blank rows between each row